# How to count number of records in a var

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.2

I have the below code which is returning me a model from database. I want to know how many records are written. I am trying to use `model.count` or `model.lenght` but its not working.

```
var model = await _repository.GetEmployees(name);
```

GetEmployees method is defined as follows:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmployees(string name)
{
    return await _dbContext.Employee
        .Where(c => c.EmpName == name).ToListAsync();
}
```

I need to know the count of records.

Comment: model is an object of c# code. for getting count you would need model.Count

Comment: Try "var count=model.Count();"

Comment: model.count is not working.

Answer (score 2):

add System.Linq to your usings.
It will give an extension method to all IEnumerables called Count()

Comment: How do you know it's an IEnumerable? Even if it is, it might be better to use `Count` or `Length` of the actual class if properly spelled. Or something else entirely, depending on what type is returned.

Comment: Because GetEmployees() is written by you ?

Comment: Uh, no, I'm not the OP. It turns out the OP edited their question and you were right. But please don't *guess*. This site is not about guessing and being lucky. If you need more information, ask for clarification, don't guess.

Answer (score 2):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmployees(string name)
{
    return await _dbContext.Employee
        .Where(c => c.EmpName == name).ToListAsync();
}
```

Since you *know* it is a `List<>` your method should return that type. Otherwise you are just lying to yourself and as a direct consequence, your program will be littered with inefficient Linq, querying already existing data, or lots and lots of `ToList` calls on things that are already materialized.

So either make it a list and subsequently use the `Count` property.

```
public async Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployees(string name)
{
    return await _dbContext.Employee
        .Where(c => c.EmpName == name).ToListAsync();
}
```

Or leave it as an `IEnumerable` because you want to not materialize it for your caller (maybe for good reason):

```
public async IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees(string name)
{
    return await _dbContext.Employee.Where(c => c.EmpName == name);
}
```

However, this is tricky for many reasons. For example the database call will only be made once the caller actually tries to enumerate this and who knows whether `_context` is still alive then.

And if you really only need the count, you should query that from the database instead of sending over hundreds of employees to your application, when a simple integer of "359" or similar would have been enough:

```
public async Task<int> GetNumberOfEmployees(string name)
{
    return await _dbContext.Employee
        .CountAsync(c => c.EmpName == name);
}
```